# Healing in the New Testament

Tags: word-study

Do you know any scriptures on healing from the New Testament? I am having a lot of issues with sickness and want to confess the word of God over myself to get healing. I pray and read God's word, but have a hard time finding the scriptures that I need.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: This site does not offer personal advice.  Please consult your pastor, priest or trusted Christian advisor.  See https://www.soulshepherding.org/article/jesus-healings-and-miracles/  and  2 Cor 12:8, 9.

Comment: _Is any sick among you? let him call for the elders of the church; and let them pray over him, anointing him with oil in the name of the Lord:_ James 5:14. Kind Regards.

Comment: Thank you for the scripture on James 5:14, I was looking for a list of scriptures. I guess I need to find another site. Thank you.